# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

I found a similar questions in stack , but they didn't help me to resolve this issue. I'm a newbie to Angular JS. (I'm calling a http post method from my client side. ) There's a text box and when user adds words to the box and click submit button I'm sending that data to my API

My Controler

```
'use strict'

export default function ($route,$rootScope,$location,$mdToast, $http , API_URL) {
  this.submitAddress = function (movieName) {

 $http.post(`${MY_URL}/movies`,movieName)

  .then(() => {

    $mdToast.show(
      $mdToast.simple()
        .textContent('Success!')
        .hideDelay(3000)
    )
  })      }}
```

From view

```
        <md-input-container>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="movieName" ng-model="mgMovies.model.movieName"/ >

      </div> -->

    </md-input-container>
```

Button

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$myController.submitAddress(mgMovies.model.movieName)">
```

From my API URL. there's a get and post method and my post method is here

```
    addresses.post = function (
  request /* : Object */,
  response /* : Object */
) /* : Promise<Object> */ {

  if (!request.body) {
    throw boom.badRequest('No request.url.params provided', 'params')
  }

  if (!request.body.movieName) {
    throw boom.badRequest('Movie name param not provided', 'params')
  }

  return libAddr.saveNewMovie(request.body.movieName)


    .then(() => {
      return response.setStatusCode(200)
  })
}
```

Error shows as

```
angular.js:14794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at responseError (http-errors-interceptor.js:20)
at processQueue (angular.js:17145)
at angular.js:17193
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18331)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18628)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:27456)
at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3785)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3773) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

Comment: issue is from somewhere else , your post does not have code url

Comment: Posted the api calling method as well

Comment: still i dont see a valid code which provides the above error

Comment: Your question does not include enough information. Please include code for your controller too.

Comment: Updated the controller as well

Comment: where is the controller code?

Comment: @sajeetharan I have updated the question already. It's as My controller

Answer (score 0):

Show the full stack trace of the error... "Trying to read property of undefined" means that this is happening somewhere, `var someObj = undefined;`  and somewhere else `someObj.url` the `.url` is accessing a property and `someObj` is undefined.  Actual name of `someObj` will be something else and reason it's `undefined` probably isn't so clear but there is a `.url` on the line it is pointing to in the stack trace and the object before the `.url` is `undefined`.

Comment: okay so on that line the `rejection` must be defined but the `rejection.config` is undefined and therefore trying to get the url property of it throws the error above... why that's the case is hard to say without more context of the interceptor.  Is that custom code (the interceptor file)?

Comment: export default function ($injector, $q) {
  'ngInject'

  let errorSheetService

  function getErrorSheet () {
    if (!errorSheetService) {
      errorSheetService = $injector.get('errorSheetService')
    }

    return errorSheetService
  }

  return {
    responseError: function (rejection) {
      if (rejection.config.url.indexOf('https://webaddress.io') > -1 ) {
        return rejection
      }

      return getErrorSheet().show(rejection.data.message).then(() => $q.reject(rejection))
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please add the code in an edit on the question if you can so it can be formatted if not let me know I'll copy it in/edit it so can get a better idea of what is being done, would help to have some explanation too... you might be able to just add a check for if `request.config` is undefined and handle that case in the interceptor correctly.

Comment: I'll add the code. Is it a problem in my Angular side or nodejs side?

Comment: Sounds like on the angular side making the assumption the config object will be present when in some cases it isn't.  The part I don't know off hand is why that config property isn't populated or what you're using there exactly and if it should always be populated. (also meant rejection.config above not request sorry for extra confusion)  You can put a `debugger;` statement before that line where it fails and open the chrome inspector to see for yourself that rejection.config is undefined but would have to step back through the trace to see how you got there and why it's undefined.